# match corresponding values in different column which has additional characters

Tags: excel, spreadsheet, vlookup

```
Column A    Column B
1111    #1111/1
2222    #2222/1
3333    #4444/1
4444
```

Given I have column A and B in Excel...is there a way I can match A and B and derive at something like this:

```
Column A    Column B
1111    #1111/1
2222    #2222/1
4444    #4444/1
```

The values in column A need to be next to their corresponding value in Column B which has additional characters in the beginning and in the end of it.

I also need to find any additional values for example **3333** which doesn't have a corresponding value in column B and they should be removed.

Comment: Does only column A have values that don't have a match in column B? Or are there values in Column B which do not have a match? Also, is there any repetition of numbers in either column?

Comment: @Jorvik77 Column A has the extra list of values that may not be in B. There are no dupes in either columns

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the search and match for you - it needs to be entered as an array formula

```
=IFNA(INDEX($B$2:$B$5,MATCH(TRUE,ISNUMBER(SEARCH(UPPER(A2),UPPER($B$2:$B$5))),0)),"")
```

To remove the blanks you can do this in another column which is also an array

```
=SMALL(IF($C$2:$C$5<>"",$A$2:$A$5),ROW()-1)
```

After that you can do an index match to get the matching value

```
=INDEX($B$2:$B$5,MATCH(A2,$A$2:$A$5,0))
```

This one last one is a regular formula, not an array

Comment: Thank you :) - can you add some annotation/explanation for the first formula for comprehension?

Comment: Sure. The formula is searching whether the value in A2 is found anywhere in B2:B5. The UPPER in this is just in case there are any letters - so that it would consider a123 to be equal to A123. If it does find the value then it will return a number which is the position of what it is searching in the string, so we do a match for whether or not there is a numberic value, and because it is an array formula it does this row by row. After this is is just a case of indexing the value that matches against the original list so that the output is the text we are searching for. Hope this makes sense :-)